# Permissions to run SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-agent

I am getting the following error message:

> Message  Executed as user: fin\jdoe. The server principal
> "fin\jdoe" is not able to access the database "abc" under the
> current security context. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 916).  The step
> failed.

I have a stored procedure that uses the following databases:
ABC
DEF
GHI

What SQL command would I have to run to give myself permission to run my stored procedure, as a SQL Server Agent Job, in the ABC database?

I can execute the stored procedure manually, I just can't schedule a job for it.

Any suggestions?

**Edit #1**

I logged into the server, without selecting any database, I selected the security folder and then under logins, I found out that I have sysadmin power.

Given that I have sysadmin power, is there something I need to do in order to execute my stored procedure? Is there a way I need to edit my permissions?

I have worked in several Business Intelligence and data analyst roles, but I have never worked as a DBA before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need sys admin perms aka SA. You might have to go ask someone to do it for you or give you the creds temporarily

Comment: @DougCoats I doubt this has anything to do with the privileges of the OP's user - more likely, the SQL Agent Service Account doesn't have privileges to run the job as the mentioned user.

Comment: You need to create a Proxy to run the job using Credentials thus granting the SQL Agent running with the user `fin\jdoe` privileges. See [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Edited my post to include more details